# Should i use static variables/methods or sending its values in a bundle?

Tags: android, optimization, static

I have a main Activity and some static variables (got values in onCreate() method).

I also have 6 other `Activities` and 1 `Broadcast Receiver` use this static variables. And they may be changed their values in a specify `Activity` or `Broadcast Receiver`.

Should i use static variables/methods or sending its values in a bundle? Which is better optimized?

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you should be using the `SharedPreferences`

Comment: Thanks for your advice. May i will take a time for study about this.

Comment: Your answer sound like not similar with my question but it is awesome. That exactly what i need. Thanks you again for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Static variables can (and will be, a lot of the times) reset when the user sends your app into the background, because the system will serialize everything that it can keep track of to the disk, to keep for later use and save RAM.
If you send your values in bundles though, all your data will be successfully saved and restored later when it's actually needed.

Comment: Thanks for your good advice. I will keep this in my head when consider using a static variables.